# How to return id of a row from v-data-table in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify-datatable

I'm currently struggling with returning the id of a specific field from each row. I need this id to use it as a parameter for a function that will be used in an action button to delete the row.
This is how my table template is looking like:

```
       <template v-slot:top>
            <v-toolbar flat>
              <v-toolbar-title>Publicații</v-toolbar-title>
              <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical> </v-divider>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="search"
                append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Caută"
                single-line
                clearable
                class="shrink"
                hide-details=""
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical> </v-divider>
              <v-btn
                color="orange"
                v-on:click="
                  changeRoute();
                  arataDialogEditare = true;
                "
                v-show="arataBtnAdaugare"
                >{{ txtBtnAdaugaNou }}
              </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:[`item.actiuni`]>
            <v-btn color="primary" fab x-small elevation="2">
              <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn
              v-on:click="deletePublication()"
              color="primary"
              fab
              x-small
              elevation="2"
            >
              <v-icon>delete_forever</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </template>
```

This is how my headers are looking like (my headers is dynamically loaded, that's why I have more than one) :

```
    headers: [],
    headersInitial: [
      {
        text: "Id publicatie",
        value: "ID",
      },
      {
        text: "Tip publicație",
        value: "tipPublicatie",
      },
      {
        text: "Nume publicație",
        value: "titluPublicatie",
      },

      {
        text: "An publicație",
        value: "an",
      },
      {
        text: "Actions",
        value: "actions",
        sortable: false,
      },
    ],
    headersFaraTipPublicatii: [
      {
        text: "Id publicatie",
        value: "ID",
      },
      {
        text: "Nume publicație",
        value: "titluPublicatie",
      },

      {
        text: "An publicație",
        value: "an",
      },
      {
        text: "Actions",
        value: "actions",
        sortable: false,
      },
    ],
    publicatii: [],
    publicatiiCuFiltru: [],
```

This is how I get my data into the table:

```
initialize() {
      this.headers = this.headersInitial;
      axios.get("https://localhost:44349/api/items/ReturnarePublicatii").then((returnPub) => {
        this.publicatii = returnPub.data;
        this.publicatiiCuFiltru = returnPub.data
      });
    },
```

Here is my delete function:

```
deletePublication() {
      let ID =  this.headersInitial.ID
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the record?')) {
        axios.get("https://localhost:44349/api/items/StergereItem/" + ID).then((returnPub) => {
        this.publicatii = returnPub.data;
        this.publicatiiCuFiltru = returnPub.data
        });
      }
    },
```

Whenever I try to delete a record, this error occurs: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400". How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ID =  this.headersInitial.ID
```

`this.headersInitial` is an array - it has no property `ID`

Your `deletePublication()` method needs to receive the id of the row as a parameter (because it can be called for different rows always with different id)

That's why Vuetify passes the actual row into a `item` slot as a prop. Replace `v-slot:item.actiuni` with `v-slot:item.actiuni="{ item }"` as shown in the [example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item). The `item` is the object (current row) and you can use it in your handler as `v-on:click="deletePublication(item.ID)`

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what i needed